# Save PDF stream into folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stream, pdf-generation, filestream

I am creating a Stream, I am able to download it as a PDF file & also able to return it as a Filestream into PDF format.

But I want to save this stream into a folder into PDF file format.

I am using some code to create stream as::

```
public void PrintInvoice(long ID)
        {

            ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
            rd.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+(@"\Reports\InvoiceDocument.rpt"));
            Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return File(stream, "application/pdf", "TestCrystal.pdf");     
        }
```

How can I save the formed stream into Folder into PDF file format?
I want to save the PDF file on Client Machine.

Comment: on server? or on Client machine? If your intention is on the client machine, then forget about it, it can't be done. If it is on server then let me know.

Comment: I want to save the PDF file on Client Machine.

Answer (score 2):

**To save file on Server -**

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     stream.CopyTo(ms);
     System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Report1.pdf"), ms.ToArray());
}
```

**To save file on Client -**

Option1 - [Using ActiveX, you Save file on Client machine without user interaction](http://jgvimalan.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/save-xml-file-in-client-machine-without-user-interaction-using-asp-net/)

Option2 - [Using Silverlight, you can put the file in IsolatedStorage available on client machine](http://progproblems.blogspot.in/2009/11/saveread-file-from-silverlight-30-in.html)

Unfortunately you cannot save file with JQuery/JavaScript, due to security issues. And there are many other options like Java Applets etc.

I do not understand the reason why do you want to save file on client machine from server side. Let user take that responsibility, I mean let user click a link and get the file from server and save it in the location of his interest. Don't you think it is security issue if server tries to save/access files on client machines. So I would suggest you to re-think your implementation and come up with different workflow.